# Message displays on system booting up

Tags: boot, bios

This message shows up when I boot my PC up. Any ideas on how or why it shows up and how I can avoid it because it didn't happen before and I suspect it started because I edited some BIOS Menu settings without understanding it's consequences entirely:

[image: Picture of boot-up screen]

Just to be clear my PC was somehow set to boot from a Live CD as default and the CD didn't have any system files on it so it kept failing to boot unless I pressed 'DEL' repeatedly to escape from that sequence and boot from the Hard Drive instead. To change this a friend edited some BIOS setting that unfortunately I cannot recall and all of a sudden this message starts to show up on booting.

Comment: it is likely because your computer is configured for network boot (PXE) in the Bios/EFI. remove network boot from the boot order, and if you have an option to enable/disable PXE, disable it. Just out of curiosity, is there actually a cable plugged into your ethernet port, or are you using Wifi as your main connection? Either way, even if network boot is first in your boot order, as long as the boot order is set to boot from the correct hard disk, it should boot up after PXE fails. What is the exact model of your laptop or motherboard? knowing that, we can tell you how to config boot order.

Comment: I'm using a Lenovo G-500s with intel core i5, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD and running Ubuntu 14.04LTS. No, there's no ethernet cable plugged in and I'm using WiFi, which is why it does boot up after PXE fails. I was just annoyed by the time lag in waiting for it to check an unnecessary condition every time I booted it up so I wanted to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to BIOS and check this settings:
Boot Priority: keep your internal HDD 1s order.
In boot menu set : Legacy boot on and UEFI 1st.
other wise make all the settings default.